# Use awk to limit output of transparent huge pages

Tags: awk

How would I use `awk` to filter the current setting of the transparent huge pages?

Example output of transparent huge pages:

```
$ cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always madvise [never]
```

I would like to output only the current setting:

```
never
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `awk` may also help you on same.

```
awk -F"[][]" 'NF{print $2}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** following is not exact code it is only for explanation purposes only.

```
-F"[][]"      ##Setting field separator as ] and [ for each line in Input_file.
'NF{          ##Checking condition here if line is NOT NULL where NF is number of fields awk variable which will be set only when a line is NOT NULL.
print $2}     ##If above condition is TRUE then print the 2nd field of current line of Input_file.
'  Input_file ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: This worked. Short and simple. Would you mind edit your answer and give a brief explanation of how `-F` and `NF` was used? (I did a 5min google and couldn't find an explanation)

Comment: @HowardLee, glad that it helped you, added the explanation too now, kindly do let me know in case of any queries too.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
awk -F'[\\]\\[]' '/always madvise/ && NF > 2 { print $2 }' /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I chose the other answer as it was shorter.

Comment: Glad you have your problem solved -- and honestly I learned something here too -- I didn't know that `'[][]'` would work as a character class containing `\[` and `\]` -- learn something new every day. :)

Comment: ... yes, looked up IEEE1003.1 today looking for the appropriate bracket expression rule. In **9.3.5 RE Bracket Expression** Rule/Definition 1, it says: *The right-bracket ( ']' ) shall lose its special meaning and represent itself in a bracket expression if it occurs first in the list (after an initial circumflex ( '^' ), if any).*